# unable to loop through an string array within angular ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a Java object returned from a servlet which I convert into a JSON and fed back to angular as a scope variable to be displayed.

This Java object along with some string variables has a string array.

This is how the JSON looks: (the below JSON is stored on $scope.detail)

```
{"details":
{"0":{"Var1":"val1","Var2":"val2","Arr1":["0","0","2",null,null,null]},
{"1":{"Var1":"val1","Var2":"val2","Arr1":["0","0","2",null,null,null]}
}
```

I am able to successfully iterate over the items using ng-repeat except for "Arr1". A few responses on the website show that I should be able to iterate using another ng-repeat but the below doesn't work for me. Please suggest. Thank You.

```
<table ng-repeat="item in detail.details">
    <tr>
        <td>item.Var1</td>
        <td>item.Var2</td>
        <td>
            <div ng-repeat="val in item.Arr1">
                  {{val}}
            </div>
         </td>
     </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: Your JSON does not seem to be correct. Check if it is valid.

Comment: Yea that is not valid - http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: There are duplicates in the Arr1. Try `ng-repeat="val in item.Arr1 track by $index"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON you have provided is not valid JSON. 
With the least modifications, I would suggest re-formatting it to look something like this:

```
{
  "details": [
     {
        "Var1":"val1","Var2":"val2","Arr1":["0","0","2",null,null,null]
     },
     {
        "Var1":"val1","Var2":"val2","Arr1":["0","0","2",null,null,null]
      }
   ]
}
```

Although this is now valid JSON, I still think you should consider reformatting your JSON even more to easily consume it by the AngularJS app.

Here is a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/eyXWKXwMXL4S1UNQEHQN?p=preview) to illustrate a solution.

Comment: Thank You all. This really helped me concentrate on the JSON rather than on the angular syntax for iterating. My error here was that in an attempt to clean the servlet response of nulls, I had ended messing up the JSON format. Once I cleared that out it worked like a charm. The Plunker was really helpful to run through my JSONs. Thanks Ben Beck.

Answer (score 0):

Check your JSON, it is not valid. The 2nd property of your details object is not structured well check for `{` and `}`, they are not placed correctly.

You can use https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ to restructure your JSON and check of errors

Below is the corrected JSON:

```
{  
   "details":{  
      "0":{  
         "Var1":"val1",
         "Var2":"val2",
         "Arr1":[  
            "0",
            "0",
            "2",
            null,
            null,
            null
         ]
      },
      "1":{  
         "Var1":"val1",
         "Var2":"val2",
         "Arr1":[  
            "0",
            "0",
            "2",
            null,
            null,
            null
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Your HTML seams OK, just add `track by $index` and print your `item.Var1` and `item.Var2` using interpolate operator

```
<table ng-repeat="item in detail.details">
    <tr>
      <td>{{item.Var1}}</td>
      <td>{{item.Var2}}</td>
      <td>
        <div ng-repeat="val in item.Arr1 track by $index">
          {{val}}
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

**Some observations as per your code :**

- Your `JSON` is not valid

  [image]

  **It should be structured like this :**

  [image]
- use **`ng-repeat="(key,val) in detail.details"`** instead of **`ng-repeat="item in detail.details"`** as `detail.details` is an object not an array.

**DEMO**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.detail = {
 "details": {
  "0": {
   "Var1": "val1",
   "Var2": "val2",
   "Arr1": ["0", "0", "2", null, null, null]
  },
  "1": {
   "Var1": "val1",
   "Var2": "val2",
   "Arr1": ["0", "0", "2", null, null, null]
  }
 }
};
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <table ng-repeat="(key,val) in detail.details">
    <tr>
        <td>{{val.Var1}}</td>
        <td>{{val.Var2}}</td>
        <td>
            <div ng-repeat="item in val.Arr1">
                  {{item}}
            </div>
         </td>
     </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```